# How to take a value from a single line of text field in one list and set it as a lookup field in another list?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I have SP 2010 and SPD 2010.
I have list A that has a single line of text column named Res ID #. This provides the source for List B as a lookup column. I want to create a WF that will put the info from Res ID # column from list A into the lookup column in List B when other List B fields are modified.

I am having trouble with coercion errors in the WF. I don't have enough info on choosing the correct fields in the Lookup Integer box. Here is what I have:

> **Field Data to Retrieve**
>
> Data Source: List A
>
> Field from Source: Res ID #
>
> Return field as: As
>   Integer (grayed out)
>
> **Find the List Item**
>
> Field: ID (this pulls from list A)
>
> Value: ? (as a default it is pulling from current list (list B) and I don't think this is correct)

Shouldn't the Value pull from the Res ID # column in list A? When I click on the *fx* button, I get another Lookup for Integer box with all of the same choices and this confuses me more. I am using WF variables to store the info from List A to set current field in List B. I have logs set to show me what the results are at each step of the WF. Sometimes the info will populate the log and other times there will be the coercian error. I have changed the Data types for the WF variables and have even had the WF complete, but no values show up in the List A lookup column.

Any thoughts or direction would be appreciated